# Extract ID of a PDF document using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I need to extract PDF identifier mentioned in the trailer section of the document. But I am not able to get that value. 
Eg. Following is mentioned in my pdf file:

```
trailer
<</Size 196/Prev 370761/Root 160 0 R/Info 158 0 R/ID[<30EB7FCBB6756E461176FBBD0CEBA7B9><DB67D6D43AE0FA4FBF8CC171FC66790A>]>>
```

I need to extract value `30EB7FCBB6756E461176FBBD0CEBA7B9`. Using the  `PdfReader.Trailer` I get a dictionary type of object if one key as 'ID' but I am not able to get the above required value from it.

Comment: Don't know who down-voted, but I see a vote to close as "off topic" claiming that this is a "why isn't this code working" question. I don't agree with that vote to close, and I compensated the down vote with an up vote ;-)

Comment: Thanks @BrunoLowagie :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Using the `PdfReader.Trailer` I get a dictionary type of object if one key as 'ID' but I am not able to get the above required value from it.

Looking at `PdfReader.Trailer` you are almost there:

```
public PdfArray GetId(string FileName)
{
    using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(FileName))
    {
        return pdfReader.Trailer.GetAsArray(PdfName.ID);
    }
}
```

This methods returns the ID of the document, an array of two byte strings.

You seem to be interested in the hexadecimal representation of the ID. You can output it like this:

```
public void PrintId(PdfArray Id)
{
    if (Id != null)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("ID: ");
        foreach (PdfObject o in Id)
        {
            builder.Append("<");
            foreach (byte b in ((PdfString)o).GetBytes())
                builder.AppendFormat("{0:X}", b);
            builder.Append(">");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
    }
}
```

*(I'm not very proficient in .Net, so there may be many more elegant ways to create a hex dump of a byte array.)*