# Difference between the ID of a pdf read from iTextSharp and pdf.js

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf.js

I am trying to parse the ID of a particular pdf ([this](https://notocol.tenet.res.in:8443/File/GetFile/6/1/Load%20Mode%20Transition.pdf)) using iTextSharp as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33261798/992795). But I get null array for ID whereas I can see that another pdfReader (pdf.js) can read the id as `77a2a5c4fc17dc3a91a072c46fe69ec0`. Why is this behaviour different? Am I expected to read the ID field from some place other than the trailer?

Answer (score 2):

Open a regular PDF with an ID in a text editor like this:

[image]

Right before where it says `startxref`, you see a dictionary (it starts with `<<`). That's the *trailer dictionary* of the PDF. One of the (optional) entries is the `/ID` which is an array containing two PDF strings.

If your PDF has such an entry, then the answer to the question [Extract ID of a PDF document using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33253523/extract-id-of-a-pdf-document-using-itextsharp) won't return `null`.

Now open your PDF in a text editor:

[image]

Again you see a dictionary (the *trailer dictonary*) before `startxref`. However, in this case, the dictionary only has three entries: `/Size` (the number of objects in the cross-reference table), `/Info` (a reference to the dictionary containing the metadata) and `/Root` (a reference to the catalog dictionary).

There is no `/ID` entry, hence iText (and iTextSharp) should return `null` (and you confirmed that they do).

Now search for the value `77a2a5c4fc17dc3a91a072c46fe69ec0` in the PDF you've opened in a text editor. You won't find that value anywhere **because it's just not there!**

**Summarized:** your question *Am I expected to read the ID field from some place other than the trailer?* is wrong. You are asking how to read something that isn't there. Your question should be: *Why is pdf.js creating an ID for PDFs that don't have one, and how do I retrieve it?* The answer to the first part is reasonable: even iText tries to create an `/ID` when you manipulate a PDF because it's good practice for a PDF to have an ID. The answer to the second part is: look in the trailer (but you already knew that).

**Conclusion:** based on feedback in the comments, it turns out the the OP is using the `fingerprint()` method in pdf.js. This method returns the first element of the ID if and ID is present. If no ID is found, and MD5 hash is returned. See the [source code](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/58c3ea08202becf007c304512c44726719acb508/src/core/core.js#L513) of the `fingerprint()` method in pdf.js.

Comment: *Right before where it says startxref, you see a dictionary (it starts with `<<`). That's the* Catalog *or* root dictionary *of the PDF* - ehem, no. it's the *trailer dictionary*, the *Catalog/root* dictionary is the one that its **Root** entry references.

Comment: Er... It was early in the morning after a busy day in Silicon Valley. Thanks for correcting me, mkl and @rhens.

Comment: So you are suggesting that the ID is just not present in the document and pdf.js is either giving some random value or generating it using some logic?

Comment: You don't have to believe me if you don't want to, but please check for yourself: open the PDF in a plain text editor and look for that ID. If you can't find it, you'll *know* that I'm not *suggesting* anything ;-)

Comment: Even I tried to search for the ID but I could not find it. But I thought may be its in some coded form that i don't understand :P. Anyways will try to find out if I can find a away to understand how pdf.js extracts ID. Thanks :)

Comment: I repeat it once more: pdf.js DOES NOT extract an ID! It CREATES an ID. If you want to see what's inside the compressed streams, use [RUPS](http://itextpdf.com/product/itext_rups)!

Comment: @labyrinth are you using `fingerprint()` in pdf.js to "extract" the ID?

Comment: Yes. I was treating fingerprint printed by pdf.js as ID but now I realize that it is different than the ID

Comment: It seems pdf.js `fingerprint()` is calculating an MD5 hash if there's no **ID**: [fingerprint() source](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/58c3ea08202becf007c304512c44726719acb508/src/core/core.js#L513)